# Docker, ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, enoent

I have a Storage constant that is used in a file called listingController.js

```
const storage = Storage({
   keyFilename: "../key/keyname.json"
});
```

Everything works fine when I'm not using Docker but after I create a Docker image and deploy it on server I get the following error:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/key/keyname.json'
at wrapError (/app/node_modules/gcs-resumable-upload/build/src/index.js:17:12)
at /app/node_modules/gcs-resumable-upload/build/src/index.js:235:19
at getToken (/app/node_modules/google-auto-auth/index.js:27:9)
at getAuthClient (/app/node_modules/google-auto-auth/index.js:233:9)
at <anonymous>
```

Here I see a problem that the **'..'** is ignored in front of the path which is why I think that file is not found.

Here is my project structure:

```
src
--- key
----- keyname.json
----- firebasekeyfilename.json
--- controller
----- listingController.js
----- firebaseController.js
```

I have tried all different combinations of file names and paths but I cannot get it to find that file.

Does anyone have a clue why this is happening?

In my firebaseController I have the following reference to a similar file in the same folder and it works fine.

```
var serviceAccount = require("../key/firebasekeyfilename");
```

The only difference is that the path is inside `require()` and I guess that requires a different path.

Been stuck with this for a couple of days now, any pointers would be appreciated, thank!

Comment: Try using an absolute file path

Comment: @CliveMakamara thanks for the comment. Absolute path will change depending on the environment!?

Comment: Use https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_filename to reliably generate the absolute directory as it will change according to the environment

Comment: using __dirname will give me the *current* absolute directory. What you are saying is that I should use that to navigate to other directories from that? '__dirname/../key/keyname.json' ?

Comment: Yes, from that directory you should be able to manipulate the path to your liking. Either as stated above or by simply finding out where the src directory lies, then doing what you need etc

Comment: Thank you for saving me time, it worked.